# Django: Make a Queryset with annotate using an object's property

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-annotate

I have a queryset in my Django `views.py`. I'm using `annotate` to add a `promo` property to each object based on each object's `id`. However this is not working:

```
    bytes = Byte.objects.filter(
        published=True
    ).annotate(
        # add path to promo image based on byte's id property
        promo=Value('../static/images/promo-'+id+'.png', output_field=CharField())
    ).order_by(
        '-publish_date'
    )
```

I get the error: `name 'id' is not defined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you try you are trying to access a **variable** id. Try using the Concat function:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

bytes = Byte.objects.filter(
    published=True
).annotate(
    # add path to promo image based on byte's id property
    promo=Concat(Value('../static/images/promo-'), 'id', Value('.png'), output_field=CharField())
).order_by(
    '-publish_date'
)
```

Reference: [Django database Functions - Concat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#concat).